# Organizing classes in Ruby script

Tags: ruby, oop, scripting

I'm writing a small game. I have:

```
class MyGame
  ...
  class_methods
  a bit of game logic
end

# after my_game unwrapped code

putss
get.chomps
methods, loops (to be DRY)
interaction with user, returning values
```

Is there a correct approach to wrap code together? Is it correct to not wrap code after my_game class in any class or module, or should I always put my code in classes/modules?

Comment: I believe you should add some more research in designing software or study some resources or go through software in github for example. Nevertheless, I provide some guidelines in an answer below.

Comment: Thanks. Still I'm not sure why you're giving me thumbs down.. My question is quite clear. I just wanted to know if I should organize my code better.

Comment: @Ann Actually, this is not a clear question. There is no such thing as _the way_ to organize code, so this is opinion-based question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wrap functionality in modules and classes, as there are some benefits to it:

a) you can easily write tests for code in classes (and for modules by including them in classes as mixins and testing the classes)
b) you have control over the visibility of functions/methods and you can actually create an interface in case you have a consumer of the game that needs to access something more than just the game class
c) it's easier to extend the functionality of parts of the game by creating new implementors of parts of the game's functionality

That said, there is no dogma on writing only in an Object Oriented way. In some cases (perhaps for scripts that will be used as command line scripts), just having some functions and code executing those functions might be enough (especially if the script is simple and short in general).

My advice regarding the structure of the little game you're building is to look for the interactions, the "verbs" that need to take place (ie the messages sent between objects) and then you'll come up with the classes that will send those messages (methods) and designing and structuring the game will get much easier I believe.

By the way, a good book that could help in the direction of designing software is the following:

[http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Object-Oriented-Design-Ruby-Addison-Wesley/dp/0321721330](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321721330)

Hope the above help.